# Get PHP command from another file

Tags: php

While using wordpress i got to know something and i also want to do that.

Like if we create a file and put all commands there. Like:-

```
$msg = "Hello"
$msg2 = Good Morning"
```

and many like this.

and on another page we need command to to show.

```
<?php $msg; ?>
```

So it shows that command. Can it be like that? If YES than how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve use next time.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `echo` to display the content of a variable rather than just putting the variable on its own.

To keep variable values across files, you can use `include(file)`

Comment: i seen this code in wordpress coding - <?php get_template_part('content'); ?> So how does it get content?

Comment: It's a wordpress function which seems to be designed to get the template part you ask for. If you ask for "content", it will give you that, I suppose.